# Not sure why my table and template are not appearing in my XSL file and having issues with Muenchian grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been working on this assignment XSL style sheet that displays employee information and groups it by department and sorts in descending order. I am using a for-each element that uses the Muenchian grouping to sort each unique department by using this location path. The assignment tells me that each time through the for-each loop, it says to write the code for the "employeeList" table. "Department" is the value for the department element.

It also tells me to insert a new template "matching" the employee element. This template is supposed to write a table row containing information on a selected employee. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="departments" match="employee" use="department" />

   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />


   <xsl:template match="/">

      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Employee Report</title>
            <link href="hbstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">
               <header>
                  <img src="hblogo.png" alt="Harris and Barnes" />
               </header>

               <h1>Employee Report</h1>

                 <xsl:for-each select="//employee[generate-id()=generate-id(key('departments', department)[1])]">
                 <xsl:sort select="department" />
                 </xsl:for-each>

             <table class="employeeList">
               <caption><xsl:value-of select="department" /></caption>
               <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Marital Status</th>
                    <th>Work Status</th>
                 </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('departments', department)">
                  <xsl:sort select="salary" order="descending" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
               </tbody>
             </table>
             </div>
         </body>

      </html>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="employee">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="position" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(salary, '$#,##0')" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="phone" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="gender" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="maritalStatus" /></td>
        <td>><xsl:value-of select="workingStatus" /></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hbemployees.xsl" ?>

<employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <employee empID="4">
      <name>Heffner, Marian</name>
      <position>Chief Operating Officer</position>
      <phone>x10962</phone>
      <email>mheffner50@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>262000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="192">
      <name>Murff, Nicolle</name>
      <position>Mgr Software Client Supp</position>
      <phone>x32524</phone>
      <email>nmurff63@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>137000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="295">
      <name>Vecchio, Art</name>
      <position>Line Worker</position>
      <phone>x12125</phone>
      <email>avecchio55@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>83000</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Part Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="294">
      <name>Lewis, Richard</name>
      <position>Met Read/Coll</position>
      <phone>x22131</phone>
      <email>rlewis19@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Production</department>
      <salary>74500</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="293">
      <name>White, William</name>
      <position>Env Asst</position>
      <phone>x03194</phone>
      <email>wwhite61@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Marketing</department>
      <salary>53500</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>single</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Contract</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="292">
      <name>Williams, John</name>
      <position>Line Wrker A</position>
      <phone>x06056</phone>
      <email>jwilliams31@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Research</department>
      <salary>70500</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>single</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="291">
      <name>Clark, David</name>
      <position>Sr Engineer</position>
      <phone>x03551</phone>
      <email>dclark16@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Production</department>
      <salary>81000</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Contract</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="290">
      <name>Sand, Robyn</name>
      <position>Dsl Sys Rep</position>
      <phone>x12823</phone>
      <email>rsand25@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Research</department>
      <salary>89000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Contract</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="191">
      <name>Michell, Eloise</name>
      <position>Mgr Cap Rptg Dist</position>
      <phone>x19826</phone>
      <email>emichell34@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>188000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>single</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="289">
      <name>Blackshear, Homer</name>
      <position>Line Wrker A</position>
      <phone>x14845</phone>
      <email>hblackshear74@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>83000</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="288">
      <name>Trumbull, Monroe</name>
      <position>Prog/Analyst</position>
      <phone>x27132</phone>
      <email>mtrumbull49@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>51500</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>single</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
```

BTW it validates but the page renders as mushed together text and numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Your `xsl:for-each` isn't doing anything currently(it is empty); put something in it so that you get something out of it... there is a syntactical error in `format-number` you've used, correct it.. And why is the input XML so big??;cut it short please(and let it be a valid XML too).

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the format number issue in my editor but not on here. Thank you. Also cut the file short. Just wanted people to get an idea of it.

Comment: "*the page renders as mushed together text and numbers*" No, that is not what happens. The page renders as an empty table with header row only.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS can you please post that as an answer? I fixed the problem thanks to you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It did until I fixed my silly error. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If - as it seems - you want a table for each department, you must place the table **inside** the `xsl:for-each` instruction.

IOW, move the closing tag `</xsl:for-each>` so that it comes immediately after `</table>`.

Note also that:

```
<td>><xsl:value-of select="workingStatus" /></td>
```

returns a cell containing nothing but a `>` character, because (1) you have an extra `>` after `<td>` and (2) there is no `workingStatus` element in the input.

Also make sure that when sorting by salary, your `xsl:sort` element has a `data-type="number"` attribute. Otherwise you will see $83,000 listed before $262,000 (in alphabetical order).